# How do you use custom data types in pandas' astype method?

Tags: pandas

How do you use custom data types in pandas' astype method? Or alternatively, how do you map a function to specific columns?

For example, say I have a "Quarter" data type:

```
class Quarter:
    def __init__(self, date):
       self.year = date.year
       self.quarter = date.quarter

   def __repr__(self):
       return f'{self.year} Q{self.quarter}'
```

I'd like to be able to say:

```
df.astype({'date':Quarter})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you just want

```
df['date'] = df['date'].map(Quarter)
```

Note that you can't change the column data type to a custom type. Columns (Series) containing custom python objects will always have a generic `object dtype`.

```
class Quarter:
    def __init__(self, date):
       self.year = date.year
       self.quarter = date.quarter
    def __repr__(self):
       return f'{self.year} Q{self.quarter}'

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('01-01-2021', periods=10, freq='2M')
})
>>> df['date']

0   2021-01-31
1   2021-03-31
2   2021-05-31
3   2021-07-31
4   2021-09-30
5   2021-11-30
6   2022-01-31
7   2022-03-31
8   2022-05-31
9   2022-07-31
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

>>> df['date'] = df['date'].map(Quarter)
>>> df['date']

0    2021 Q1
1    2021 Q1
2    2021 Q2
3    2021 Q3
4    2021 Q3
5    2021 Q4
6    2022 Q1
7    2022 Q1
8    2022 Q2
9    2022 Q3
Name: date, dtype: object

# 'date' column data type
>>> df['date'].dtype

dtype('O')

# data type of each element of 'date' column 
>>> df['date'].map(type)

0    <class '__main__.Quarter'>
1    <class '__main__.Quarter'>
2    <class '__main__.Quarter'>
3    <class '__main__.Quarter'>
4    <class '__main__.Quarter'>
5    <class '__main__.Quarter'>
6    <class '__main__.Quarter'>
7    <class '__main__.Quarter'>
8    <class '__main__.Quarter'>
9    <class '__main__.Quarter'>
Name: date, dtype: object
```

---

> I'm looking for something that allows for method chaining. I could do `df.assign(date = lambda x: x['date'].map(Quarter))` but that gets quite messy with multiple columns

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.5/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html?highlight=agg%201%201%205):

```
>>> df.agg({'date': Quarter})

      date
0  2021 Q1
1  2021 Q1
2  2021 Q2
3  2021 Q3
4  2021 Q3
5  2021 Q4
6  2022 Q1
7  2022 Q1
8  2022 Q2
9  2022 Q3
```

If you want to change in-place, you can define a generic function that receives a DataFrame `df` and  dictionary with the format `{'column of df': func_to_apply_to_column}`, similarly to `astype`, and applies each function to the respective column accordingly. To use it with method chaining use [`DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.5/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html?highlight=pipe%201%201%205).

```
def map_columns(df, col_func_dict):
    for col, func in col_func_dict.items():
        df[col] = df[col].map(func)
    return df

>>> df.pipe(map_columns, {'date': Quarter})

      date
0  2021 Q1
1  2021 Q1
2  2021 Q2
3  2021 Q3
4  2021 Q3
5  2021 Q4
6  2022 Q1
7  2022 Q1
8  2022 Q2
9  2022 Q3
```

Comment: Thank you, although that works I'm looking for something that allows for method chaining. I could do `df.assign(date = lambda x: x['date'].map(Quarter))` but that gets quite messy with multiple columns.

Comment: @MycchakaKleinbort I updated the answer with that requirement. Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, that works. I've made a new question to ask what is the best pandas method for this (if there is one), but your custom code works. FYI note you are modifying the df inplace, but I can adjust that if I want immutability. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70005612/how-do-you-modify-columns-in-pandas-via-method-chaining

Comment: On that note I could always register an extension to Pandas if there is no inbuilt method.

Comment: @MycchakaKleinbort I was overcomplicating, I've update the answer again. You just need to use `DataFrame.agg`. But only the mapped columns are selected.

Comment: @MycchakaKleinbort I know that I'm changing in-place, but that seems irrelevant if you are using in the middle of the chain. You can just copy the DataFrame in the beginning of the function

Comment: `.agg` is great. It has a similar issue to .apply and .transform in that non-mapped columns get dropped.

Comment: @MycchakaKleinbort I don't think there is a built-in way to do that unless you use `assign`, which is quite verbose as you said it. But you can easily create a custom function that does that and pass it to `pipe`. I will respond in the other thread.