# How do you modify columns in Pandas via method chaining?

Tags: pandas

What is the best pandas method to apply specific functions to specific columns?

Let

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[1,2,3], 'C':[1,2,3]})
```

Suppose I want to double the values in column `'A'` and halve the values in column `'B'`, and keep column `'C'` unchanged.

I know I could do

```
df['A'] = df['A'] * 2
df['B'] = df['B'] / 2
```

but I'm looking for something that allows for method chaining.

This comes close:

```
df.apply({'A':lambda x: x*2, 'B':lambda x: x/2})
```

But by default it drops column `'C'`

The other alternative I know is an abuse of the `.assign` method. Ie

```
df.assign(**{'A':lambda x: x['A']*2, 'B':lambda x: x['B']/2})
```

But I'm sure Pandas has a method for what I'm looking to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latter code you propose is absolutely not an abuse: [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) accepts a callable and there is even an example in the documentation.

```
>>> df.assign(temp_f=lambda x: x.temp_c * 9 / 5 + 32)
          temp_c  temp_f
Portland    17.0    62.6
Berkeley    25.0    77.0
```

I would personnally use:

```
df.assign(A=lambda d: d['A']*2,
          B=lambda d: d['B']/2)
```

*NB. If you have a look at my [pandas answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A16343464+%5Bpandas%5D+assign+lambda), you will see that I am using it all the time ;)*

###### alternative: eval

You could also use [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) (only one expression per line is allowed):

```
df.eval('''A = A*2
           B = B/2''')

# or
df.eval('A = A*2\nB = B/2')
```

***Warning:** while `eval` is nice, it is quite slower than `assign`*

Comment: Thank you. Using the dictionary allows you arbitrary column names ;)

Comment: @MycchakaKleinbort yes, this is actually the only time I use it, otherwise I like the parameter way to avoid creating an intermediary dictionary ;)

Comment: Can this be used with `MultiIndex`? Assign doesn't seem to be usable, as you cannot pass the hierarchical name, even when using an expanded dictionary.

Comment: @mfurseman what would be the exact use-case?(if too complex, maybe ask a new question, linking to this one)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom function that receives the DataFrame (`df`) and the dictionary of functions, and first applies each function to the respective column using `DataFrame.transform`, and then adds the unchanged columns.

Since that your use case seems to apply vectorized transformations that only depend on the given column, using `DataFrame.transform` should be faster than using `DataFrame.apply`. `DataFrame.transform` also allows you to apply a list of functions to the same column.

```
def map_columns(df, func_dict, *args, **kwargs):
    # Transform each column
    df_trans = df.transform(func_dict, *args, **kwargs)
    # get the unchanged columns
    other_cols = df.columns.difference(df_trans.columns)
    # add the unchanged columns to the final result
    df_trans[other_cols] = df[other_cols]
    return df_trans
```

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[1,2,3], 'C':[1,2,3]})
>>> df

   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3

>>> map_columns(df, {'A':lambda x: x*2, 'B':lambda x: x/2})

   A    B  C
0  2  0.5  1
1  4  1.0  2
2  6  1.5  3
```

To use it with method chaining just pass the function to `DataFrame.pipe`

```
>>> ( 
  df.pipe(map_columns, {'A':lambda x: x*2, 'B':lambda x: x/2})
    .mul(-1)
    # (...)
)

   A    B  C
0 -2 -0.5 -1
1 -4 -1.0 -2
2 -6 -1.5 -3
```