# How could I put a large number in a datatype in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have numbers in range from 0 to 3.4е+23.
The "maximum" data format in this library is 'int64' (that is Хе+18).

Help me, please. How could I 'read' that data, because I want to train them with Sklearn. Also I can't apply StandartScaler/Normalizer for data, because numbers are large!

I change datatype like this:

```
df['df'] = df['df'].astype('int64')
```

Do you know some ways to change datatype?
Or you know the way to do something for the whole DataFrame?

Comment: `sklearn` works with `numpy`.  Since `numpy` doesn't anything larger than `int64` `sklearn` can't either.  `python` does allow large integers, but an object dtype array with those will be slow, if it works at all.

Comment: Just use `np.float64`, why you use ints?

Comment: @dankal444 Thank you, but it was a sample. I use float64, but it still doesn't work:  "ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')." 
P.S. I have no NaN values, or float32. I'll be glad for your help

Comment: without any reproducible code it will be hard to help you, if sklearn tells you float32 it means you provided float32

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring first a custom type based in the allowed in python large int?
I haven't tested it, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70004772/how-do-you-use-custom-data-types-in-pandas-astype-method) there is a way to use custom data types in Pandas

Answer (score 0):

Could you normalise the data? I.e. convert to percentage. Maybe

```
X_normalisedValue = (X - X_meanValue) / stdDev (X)
```